# Android: Save the conversation during the call

Tags: android

I want to ask whether it is possible in android to record an ongoing phone conversation. I was able to record what was being spoken in microphone, but not the audio coming from other end.

I tried it using MediaRecorder.AudioSource.VOICE_CALL value, but with no success.

Any help ????

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are many similar questions (Search for `Android record call`), but they all suggest that it's not possible with the current API without i.e. replacing the current phone application.